# C++ Containers and right hand side

Tags: c++, pointers, containers

I've read today that you should not use the STL containers for auto_ptr because of 
the fact that the auto_ptr deletes it rhs value in the = operator.

So i have 2 question :

1) Does this mean that all classes that have this behavior should not be used in containers?

2) what sort of containers can you use?

Comment: Rather than look for an alternative container type, you might want to look for an alternative smart pointer type (`std::unique_ptr` for example).

Comment: *"Does this mean that all classes that have this behavior should not be used in containers?"* - There just shouldn't be any classes having this behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) Does this mean that all classes that have this behavior should not
>   be used in containers?

Yes indeed, because that is not correct copying behaviour, since the copy is not equal to the source afterwards but destroys the source. This is kind of a broken implementation of move-semantics before C++11, required for the strict unique ownership semantics of `std::auto_ptr`.

> 2) what sort of containers can you use?

The real answer is actually, that classes having this behaviour (a copy constructor/assignment destroying its source) should just not exist. And fortunately this is not needed anymore nowadays, since C++11 has proper move-semantics, which realize exactly this destructive copy but in a safe way (simply said, only when the source is really not needed anymore).

Therefore `std::auto_ptr` is deprecated and should not be used anymore. It has been replaced by `std::unique_ptr` which is movable but not copyable. But since C++11 containers rather move their elements than copy when appropriate, a `std::unique_ptr` can be used perfectly inside of standard containers. You just cannot copy the container or fill it with a single object which would require copies of `std::unique_ptr`s, but those operations should not work anyway, since they are conceptually wrong for unique ownership semantics.

And as a side note, if you actually chose `std:auto_ptr` for a reason, that is you want unique ownership semantics, then a `std::shared_ptr` (as suggested by other answers) is plain wrong since it exhibits shared ownership. `std::unique_ptr` is today's `std::auto_ptr`. Never spam `std::shared_ptr`s where `std::unique_ptr`s (or even raw pointers, but from your question I rule that option out) are appropriate.

Comment: Unless you have to.  Practically speaking, most programmers can't use C++11 yet, and if they need pointers to owned objects in a container (which should be very, very rare), then `boost::shared_ptr` is about the only game in town.

Answer (score 2):

Auto pointer has a very strict ownership: it and only it is responsible for the lifetime of the object it points at. If you copy an `auto_ptr`, you lose the reference to what it pointed at.

The problem is in the way STL containers do their stuff. For example, when you are adding an element, the container might expand to get more memory, which leads to copying all the values to the new memory, which, itself, leads to losing the auto_ptrs.

I **think** that associative containers might not copy themselves entirely when they allocate additional memory, but I'm absolutely not sure, if someone can confirm it, please post a comment, or just edit my answer. Anyway, you'd better not risk it.

Also note that `Auto_ptr` is deprecated since C++0x, it is advised to use `unique_ptr` instead. In your case, `std::shared_ptr` will probably do the trick, unless you really need unique ownership for those objects of yours.

Comment: *"In your case, std::shared_ptr will probably do the trick"* - No it won't (at least not if he chose `std::auto_ptr` for a reason), since `std::shared_ptr` manages shared ownership, which is conceptually wrong when working with unique ownership. No need to spam `shared_ptr`s where `unique_ptr`s are appropriate (and they can be used in containers, since C++11 containers rather move than copy).

Comment: @Chris, ahh, that's a nice point, I totally forgot that the OP might _need_ unique ownership, and was talking just about the containers... I'll edit it, thanks.

Comment: No, `unique_ptr` should be the default smart pointer- not `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly.
In general, sequence container elements must be CopyConstructible and Assignable. This means that they require:

- public copy constructor
- public assignment operator

Asociative containers (set<> and map<>) also must provide strict weak ordering, i.e. `operator <` must be defined (or a dedicated comparison function).

Chapter 23.1 of C++ standard provides detailed requirements.

Comment: In your example insertion, doesn't `a[2]` get set to `NULL` in the first copy (and likewise `a[1]` in the second). So there shouldn't be anything deleted incorrectly here and it should actually work.

Comment: you are right. I have removed the incorrect part until I find time to describe the correct scenario.